# Need advice on writing queries using COUNT, SUM and DATE

Tags: sqlite, date, count, sum

Although I've studied the literature online, the queries I am writing are not producing the numbers I need. I'm using Hedgehog AS, which according to the literature, is using SQLite version 3.36.2.

Here's what's happening. The app records daily bird counts in bird_table. Once a month, on count day, the user needs to produce a report which includes:

- number of birds seen on count day
- number of species seen on count day
- number of species NOT seen on count day

For this example, count day is 01-27.

Table: bird_table.

| birdName. | birdTotalcount | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue Jay. | 5. | 01-27. |
| Chickadee. | 10. | 01-27. |
| Shrike. | 1. | 01-14. |
| Purple Finch | 4. | 01-26. |
| Morning Dove | 3. | 01-25. |

Tried different iterations of the following queries:

Get number of species on count day.
Query result should be 15. I'm getting 0.
...

```
SELECT COUNT(birdTotalcount) FROM bird_table WHERE timeStamp = DATE('now')
```

...
Get number of species NOT seen on count day. 
Query result should be 2. I'm getting 0.
...

```
SELECT COUNT(birdTotalcount) FROM bird_table WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN DATE('now -1 month') AND ('now')
```

...
Get number of birds on count day.
Query result should be 3. I'm getting NULL.
...

```
SELECT SUM(birdTotalcount) FROM bird_table WHERE timeStamp = DATE('now')
```

...
Once these queries are finished, the app is finished. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Ian. May I ask, how did you fix the table? I see no changes in the code.

Comment: Your query will never match any rows because `date()` will never return a string that matches your `timestamp` column.

Comment: Ok, went back into my code and changed simple date format from MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DD to match DATE() string format. That fixed two of three queries. The query using DATE('now', '-1 month') is still returning 0.   Thanks Shawn.